# how to put filters into Aws elemental medialive live video

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mobile, aws-elemental, aws-media-live

How do I add filters or process the live video stream in Aws elemental medialive like putting face filters and AR effects in my own code?

Answer (score 0):

MediaLive does not have an in-built capability to apply filters to live video stream.

You might want to look into [Amazon Rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/?blog-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&blog-cards.sort-order=desc) service. This service enables you to identify objects, people, text, scenes, and activities in images and videos, as well as detect any inappropriate content using machine learning. You will use the service API to query the image or video stored on S3.

Here is a [good primer](https://youtu.be/v662kWVBmdc) for this service's capabilities.